# Problema com class org.hibernate.validator.InvalidValue ao fazer upgrade do Hibernate 3.X para 4.X

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee

Tenho um projeto desenvolvido usando *JBoss Seam 2.2.2.Final* juntamente com **Hibernate 3.6**. Estou tentando **fazer um upgrade deste projeto subindo e migrando as versões do componentes** que ele usa. Uma dessas migrações é subir a versão do Hibernate **para a versão 4.6.3.Final**, que na data dessa postagem é a última versão estável.

Como o projeto está no Maven, a primeira coisa que fiz, foi atualizar as dependências do projeto subindo as versões do Hibernate. Da seguinte forma:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.4.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.4.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.4.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

No entanto, ao fazer as atualizações de versões no `pom.xml`, o projeto começou a apresentar erro de compilação justamente em algo relacionado ao Hibernate. Veja o trecho de código abaixo:

```
ResourceBundle bundle = SeamResourceBundle.getBundleNamed(NOME_BUNDLE);
StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder("");
msg.append(bundle.getString(MSG_GERAL));
StatusMessages.instance().add(msg.toString()); //Erro ocorre aqui
```

Na quarta linha do trecho acima, ocorre um erro relacionado a classe `org.hibernate.validator.InvalidValue` ([link documentação](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/api/org/hibernate/validator/InvalidValue.html)). O erro que ocorre é mostrado pelo Eclipse:

> The type org.hibernate.validator.InvalidValue cannot be resolved. It
>   is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Alguém sabe como corrigir esse problema? Ou sabem algum *workaround* para isso?

Answer (score 1):

O hibernate validator foi atualizado na versão 4 do hibernate.

Adicione nas suas dependências:

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
     <artifactId>hibernate-validator-legacy</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

Para manter a compatibilidade.